# Course Assignment Algorithm with weighted cost system

Tags: algorithm, heuristics

So I am trying to make and algorithm that attempts to find the ideal configuration of scheduling for a school. The inputs that the algorithm is given is the following;

- A list of 10 course requests from each student, in lowering order of preference
- A list of what courses each teacher is capable of teaching
  The program must assign 7 courses to each student, and each teacher may have at most 6 classes that they can teach. There is no hard cap on the number of students in a class, I wanted to implement a system in which there is a cost to add each new student to a class which increases exponentially after a certain point(35 or so). Using the cost system I also wanted to implement a system in which adding more students to a class is so cost ineffective that it is more ideal to request for a new teacher that can teach that class which can be sent back to the human to evaluate, which can also be overridden. Also if there is a case in which none of the requested classes can be offered to a student for some reason, that case can be thrown to a human who can manually solve that case.

I know how to implement this roughly but the main question that I had was that, is the ideal solution even achievable? Because I vaguely remember this kind of problem being similar to the traveling salesman so idk. If this is not a solvable perfectly, then how should I go about implementing a heuristic solution.

I don't have much experience with heuristics, and I am still a student so apologies in advance.

I have attempted to directly implement the solution and realized that most likely this problem would not be solvable in reasonable time due to too many moving factors to try and use an algorithm to solve